# Commercial Plugins and Solo Licensing?

Tags: plugins, license

Brand new Craft user.  Second day playing with it, and so far, loving it!

I believe the Solo license allows a Freelancer to roll off personal (for her own use) implementations for free -- even if those sites have a commercial purpose.

I understand this to mean I may power more than one site for free under the terms of the Solo license.

**Question:** Does this Solo licence freedom extend to paid plugins?

For example, I want to purchase the commercial Enupal Backup plugin.  I would like to use it on my *two* Solo-licensed Craft websites.  Can I do it, or must I purchase the plugin twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, that's up to each individual plugin developer. But realistically, the *vast* majority of commercial plugins are only valid for a single site.

If it's a paid plugin, you'll probably need to pay for it on each site independently.

> *"I may power more than one site for free under the terms of the Solo license."*

It's important to realize that you're actually working with *multiple* licenses in this case... they just all happen to be Solo (aka free). Each site has its own license, you are not sharing a Solo license across multiple sites.